# Using Subclipse in own application

Tags: svn, rcp, subclipse

i want to use Subversion in a rcp application for the versioning part.To get access to subversion i would like to use Subclipse.

I could copy the subclipse .jars from the plugins folder from eclipse, but there has to be a better way e.g. download a feature or plugin for subclipse.

Is there any way to get this done? Or do you have some experience with other plugins which provide support for subversion? The plugin should be free to use.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Subclipse (or any plugin) in an RCP application, the first thing you have to do is look at the feature/plugin requirements and make sure your RCP application will satisfy them.  If it does, then including the Subclipse features and plugins would be the easiest way to do this.  Will your RCP application include the Update Site UI?  If so, you could just install Subclipse from its update site.  Otherwise, download the zipped update and copy the features and plugins you need into your application.